# How do you specify an icon for a RichCombo item in the toolbar

Tags: ckeditor

I have a custom CKEditor plugin for selecting various app specific links to insert into the rich text box.

It makes use of the addRichCombo to define the menu and items.

Is there any way in CKEditor to specify an icon to appear in the toolbar instead of the label text of the RichCombo dropdown toolbar item ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. CKEditor API doesn't provide such feature unless you implement it ;-) Only toolbar buttons can have drop-down menus with icon, i.e.:

[image: SCAYT dropdown]

Comment: To clarify: the CKEditor element type that can have an icon and a drop down is called `menuButton`, defined [here](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.ui.menuButton). [SCAYT](http://ckeditor.com/addon/scayt) (in the picture) is the only example I've found that actually uses it, which is a shame as it's horribly complicated and difficult to understand. I'd love to see a simple example.